# How to keep Secure boot when dual booting ubuntu 16.04 with windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm new to Linux and I just successfully dual-booted my Windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04. The deal is I would like to maintain Secure Boot as enabled. When I first installed ubuntu and restarted my PC, GRUB did not show up and the pc immediately booted to windows. What I did to fix this was to do a live boot of ubuntu and use boot-repair.

After rebooting, an error occurred and told me that I needed to disable secure boot. I did so and at the next reboot, GRUB was working fine but at the cost of disabling secure boot.

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows should be in the same mode, UEFI.  In UEFI mode, the bootloader for Ubuntu is shimx64.efi, which then runs grubx64.efi, and that's never been a problem that I've heard for years, so if you are booting grubx64.efi directly, that's your problem.  Post the boot-repair output link in your question so we can tell what's going on.

Comment: In my experience, when in the boot menu, you see 2 entries for your Live USB. One with UEFI and one without. Choose the UEFI.

Comment: Did you try to install proprietary drivers like nVidia, AMD and some wireless drivers? Those are integrated into kernel and then kernel does not qualify for secure boot. You can run vanilla Ubuntu with Secure Boot on, or add proprietary drivers.  Secure Boot is primarily marketing by Microsoft that provides minimal protection for a system that has  a historical reputation of virus. But those virus were not in most cases related to booting. Sony's DRM (music prevention) related take-over of the MBR in BIOS systems years ago was the only major boot virus.

Comment: I found the source of my misery. Apparently my ubuntu got installed in Legacy mode. So I decided to redo the whole thing. I uninstalled ubuntu using OS-uninstall package from linux and deleted it's partitions. I made another bootable GPT UEFI usb disk. this time I went into live mode to check if my pc was booting the usb in UEFI mode only to find out that it does not. It was booting the usb in legacy mode. I went into my BIOS firmware but there's no specific option to boot usb in uefi mode, however the BIOS was set to UEFI mode so the situation is confusing now.

Comment: Ivan, it's unclear if you've gotten a working installation or not. If not, I recommend you read [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) and [My page on installing Linux on EFI systems.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) If you still have problems after that, please post details of what's causing the difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I looked into each one, and the info I got from them helped in solving this issue. Though, I still find my case to be a very weird one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed my problem. The initial problem was that I unintentionally installed my ubuntu in Legacy mode. I uninstalled ubuntu OS and started from scratch by making another bootable USB via Rufus. When I booted this said USB into live mode, I found out that the pc was booting it in legacy mode despite my bios being set to UEFI.

What worked for me was to make a bootable USB via disk part in the windows command line and mounting the ISO then copying the contents into the USB. This booted into UEFI mode. I then proceeded to manual install ubuntu. I chose the windows EFI partition as the device where I place ubuntu bootloader. After that, I had to force grub to show by means of bcdedit command. All was well after that.

This case is quite weird for me and I would be glad to hear from you guys why rufus did not work. I use an Acer aspire E 14 E5-475G-30KY. The firmware installed is InsydeH2O v1.01.